# How can I edit the default git merge message

Tags: git, git-merge

Since Version 1.7.10, I now have to provide a message when merging an upstream commit.

Is there a way to edit the default contents of this message?

Every time I merge, I am simply deleting the comments and saving.

I'd like to remove that part permanently.

I do not wish to turn the message feature off entirely with **mergeoptions = --no-edit** however.

Comment: _I am simply deleting the comments_ - by comments, are you referring to lines beginning with #? You don't have to delete those, they are excluded from the message automatically.

Comment: I was referring to them, yes, that's good to know that they are excluded, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case, you say that you are deleting the comments and saving. That is an unnecessary step - lines beginning with # are automatically excluded from the message:

```
$ git commit

  1 Commit title
  2 
  3 Some message content
  4 
  5 #A comment
  6 
  7 Some more message content
  8 
  9 # Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
 10 # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
 11 # On branch master
 12 # Changes to be committed:
 13 #       new file:   b
 14 #

$ git log
commit ceb148a2c26236b0e72e6befa818bce83f252a9a
Author: Me
Date:   Fri Jan 29 07:27:03 2016 +0200

    Commit title

    Some message content

    Some more message content
```

Answer (score 0):

> Every time I merge, I am simply deleting the comments and saving.

You can use the `commit -m` command to pass any message as your commit message.
Git does not allow empty messages when committing.

---

#### `commit.template`

There is **`commit.template`** configuration variable.

> [**commit.template**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)
>
> Specify a file to use as the template for new commit messages.
> "~/" is expanded to the value of $HOME and "~user/" to the specified user’s home directory.

Comment: This isn't about the commit message, it's the merge message I want to edit.